# Get the corresponding element in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, nodes

I have two `tr`'s which correspond to each other. I want to make it so if user passes in the `date`... it gets the by its `data-date` then look for the corresponding `element` in `tbody`.

I have got the first part right... this gets me the `index`:

```
var index = $("[data-date='" + item.start + "']").index();
```

Now... I am having trouble getting its corresponding `tbody` element.

I have tried:

`$("[data-date='" + item.start + "']").closest('thead').next('tbody')`

but it comes as empty.

So once I have the `tbody`... i can go to the `nth` child using the `index`

```
<div class="fc-content-skeleton">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2017-07-23"><span class="fc-day-number">23</span></td>
            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2017-07-24"><span class="fc-day-number">24</span></td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="fc-event-container" rowspan="2">
               <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end">
                  <div class="fc-content"> <span class="fc-title">100</span></div>
               </a>
            </td>
            <td class="fc-event-container">
               <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end">
                  <div class="fc-content"> <span class="fc-title">100</span></div>
               </a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select the `<td>` element within `tbody > tr` element?

Comment: How does the user "pass in" the date? I don't see any input fields. Where does `item.start` come from? Please post all of your relevant code.

Comment: @guest271314 yes... exactly

Comment: From the GET url... `item.start` is a date like this `2017-07-24`.. i m doing all this in an ajax call @ScottMarcus

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq()`

```
$("tbody tr td").eq(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector works here. I made some console tests and the tbody was found without any problem.

```
> jQuery("[data-date='2017-07-23']").closest('thead').next('tbody').length
> 1
```

The problem can be related to the value of `item.start`. Check if its correct.

Comment: Nope.. that wouldn't work... parents gets all the tables on the page